# Broadcast task to all workers with redis and celery

Tags: python, redis, celery, broadcast

**I try that:** 
**main.py**

```
import tasks
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = tasks.add.apply_async(([4, 4]), queue='broadcast_tasks')
    result.ready()
    value = result.get()
    print(value)
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu.common import Broadcast
app = Celery('tasks',
             broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
             backend='redis://localhost:6379/1',
             include=['tasks'])
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)
task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
timezone = 'UTC'

app.conf.task_queues = (Broadcast('broadcast_tasks'),)
app.conf.task_routes = {'tasks.add': {'queue': 'broadcast_tasks'}}


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**I'd like to broadcast task to all workers with redis (broker and backend) and celery, but I didn't achieve, can you help me please ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The celery team is merging the corresponding issue:
https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3934

This should be available in the next release (I hope).